# regex finding elements in xml which contain attributes whose values contain two periods

Tags: regex, xml

I'm searching some `xml` and my tool is regex. (my only tools in this case are editors so I"m using either eclipse or notepad++). I need to find all elements which contain attributes that have values containing two periods not adjacent.
so it would find `attr1` and `attr3` in this:

```
<myelement attr1 = "ab.cd.ef", attr2="ab", attr3="zy.sa.xa"/>
```

I've tried this and variations in notepad++

```
^(([^\"\.])*(\")[^\"\.]*[\.][^\"\.]*[\.][^\"\.]*[\"])+$
```

but it isn't picking up second attributes with values containing two periods.

I'm going to keep trying but if someone can point me to an answer I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Cannot you search for `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\s*=\s*"[^".]*\.[^."]+\.[^"]*"` (possibly for the part after the `=` symbol only) and skip the probably few false positives when you step through the results (assuming that you search through a dialog of the editor and not by programmatic means) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do this with regex.

Unless you create a monster regex that will create a blackhole swallowing all the life in the Earth (politely saying of course).

Bear in mind that you don't have logic in regex you just use pattern matching, for instance a number is just a number you can't say `if I get 1 then get 3 also` in a simple way.

You can use **if then else** in regex like:

```
(?(?=condition)(then1|then2|then3)|(else1|else2|else3))
```

But what you want to do is to nest if conditions with multiple conditions for each case, like `if 1 then 3 | if 2 then 4 | if 3 then 5` creating an enormous pattern nested.

Another regex approach would be to have multiple regex lookarounds (look ahead in this case) what will do your regex impossible to read.

I think you might find more useful a **Xpath** or **Xquery** expressions for this. That it's a better approach to match xml than regex.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm searching some xml and my tool is regex.

That's a bit like saying that you are cutting down trees and your tool is a screwdriver. Get the right tool for the job: an XML parser and an XPath engine.